# Swift adjust Emoji size

Tags: ios, swift, emoji

I would like to change the size of an Emoji. However, I have been searching documentation on how to do this with no luck. Is it possible to adjust the size of an Emoji before sending it.

Pseudocode:

```
if ( textField.text.isSingleEmoji ){
    // return textField.text.enlargeSize
}
```

Comment: Set a bigger font on the text field or use an attributed string and set a larger font on the Emoji part of the string.

Comment: that a very good suggestion thank you

Comment: is this in a chat/messaging app?

Comment: yes it is a chat app

Answer (score 0):

I was trying to make GuessTheFlag game. Instead of putting the flags with photo assets. I wanted make it with flag emoji. Here is the solution for how to increase size of emoji with Swift.

Increasing emoji's font size for button:

```
var countryTurkey = ""
button.setTitle(countryTurkey, for: .normal)
button.titleLabel?.font = .systemFont(ofSize: 120.0)
```

Also please note that style of the button needs to be Default. In order to do that click to the button, select the Attributes inspector and select the Style to "Default"

Increasing emoji's font size for label:

```
var countryTurkey = ""
label.text = countryTurkey
label.font = .systemFont(ofSize: 120)
```